# How to send an acknowledgement of socket connection close ? ( How to detect certain keywords to close a connection ? )

Tags: android, sockets, serversocket, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I am developing an application similar to share it . But I am using wifidirect to establish connection . I have implemented everything except two things.

```
 1) Cancelling some of the files that are in waiting list to be transferred .
      (I need to tell other device by clicking on a X mark that I don't want certain files to be 
       transferred , so drop them .) 


 2) How to close a connection in one of the device and let other device know about the connection status immediately.
```

I am unable to find how to do it . When I look at shareit , I found that they implemented these features but how did they do it . Did they use multiple socket connections ? I tried it too but no use .

Any Ideas are appreciated .    Thankyou .

Comment: What is so difficult telling the app on the other device what you dont want or that you are going to close?

Comment: i opened a socket conn between two devices and while the transmission is going on if I press on X mark the other device should be notified and if I send some kind of keyword it  wouldn't recognise on the other end as it merges with the ongoing transmission data . That is why I find it difficult . Can you tell me how to achieve that if u got a solution in a brief way . Thank you @b

Comment: You can read from and write to a socket simultanuously.

Comment: Consider I am sending 3 files from Device A to Device B .After sometime if I decide to cancel sending file 2 ,device B should be notified immediately about it . I was already sending some data from A to B and if I send the file cancelled message to B , how to detect it at B exactly at that time as B is receiving data as bytes . Thanyou @blackapps

Comment: `After sometime if I decide to cancel sending file 2 ,device B should be notified immediately about it . ...` Strange scenario. I would think that device B would conclude that it did not want the second file so B had to inform A.

Comment: As you did not tell the used scenario and protocol between the two devices we do not know what is going on. So how could we give advice? As you have seen the first misunderstanding was already there.

Comment: Why, while you are sending file 1, B should be informed immediately that the second file will not come?

Comment: If you have send the first file you could tell B that a second file is coming or that a second file is cancelled. For me that would be in time. It is just the protocol that makes all possible.

Comment: You did not tell us that at start of connection A sent a list of filenames to B. But apparently you did. But did not tell us.

Comment: yeah during the start of the connection, device A sends the details of the files to be sent like size, file name etc .. to deice B . Protocols used is of course TCP(Java sockets) .  As the list of file details are already received by B , now I want it to know that one of the files in that list is cancelled . Thank you

Comment: I already told you how you could do that with a suitable communication protocol. And i was not talking about tcp/ip but about the protocol your app uses to communicate between A and B. You make that protocol.